# Font size CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a font-size change to a specific P tag in my CSS.

I have made a new class .mainbg p { xxxx } but this doesn't work. Whats strange is that the same class worked when I added text-shadow for that p. I don't understand why it wont work for this.

I have added the CSS class

```
.mainbg p {
  font-size: bold!important;
}
```

Which also did nothing.

```
<section aria-label="home" class="mainbg" id="home">

<!-- intro -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="overlay-main v-align">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11">

    <h1 class="onStep" data-animation="animbouncefall" data-time="300">LOUIS WALLACE CONSTRUCTION</h1>
    <div class="onStep" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-time="600" id="slidertext">
      <h3 class="main-text">Oroville General Contractor</h3>
      <h3 class="main-text">Over A Decade Of Experience</h3>
      <h3 class="main-text">All Phases Of Construction</h3>
    </div>
    <p class="onStep" data-animation="animbouncefall" data-time="900" >No matter how large or small the project, we ensure that your project is completed with precision and professionalism. We take pride in our quality craftsmanship, our attention to detail, and our open line of communication with each and every customer. With each project, we understand that our role is about more than simply putting up walls — it’s about ensuring that your vision is turned into a reality.
```

The only CSS i can find in my template is an animated css:

```
.onStep{ opacity:0; }
```

When i search for any other CSS of onStep i see nothing, other than javascript. Stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried `font-size: bold!important;` but that is a `font-weight` property, not a `font-size` one. That's the reason why it is not working. 
If you want to change the size of the font you should use some kind of units, either px, em... like:

```
font-size: 40px;
```

If you want to make the text bolder you could also use:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Comment: omg i cant believe it was that simple lol. wow i didnt even catch that.

Comment: Ye right? Sometimes the little easy things are the harder to spot because we overlook them! Glad we found the error. I would appreciate if you could mark the question as solved by pressing the check. Have fun coding!